# Project Euler 8 in C++, I don't know what's wrong

Tags: c++, algorithm

The problem [from here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8): find `nbAdjacent` digits in `nStr` with highest product.  So I stored the number as a string and everything my code prints is correct yet the final result is wrong, I can't figure out why... I've continued Project Euler in the meantime but this is bugging me.
Here's my code:

```cpp
std::string nStr = "731...50";  // a 1000-digit number
uint64_t prod = 1;
int nbAdjacent = 13;
int max = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <=988; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < nbAdjacent; j++)
    {
        // yes i thought about that ;)
        prod *= nStr[i + j] - '0';
    }
    if (prod > max)
    {
        max = prod;
        for (int j = 0; j < nbAdjacent-1; j++)
            std::cout << nStr[i + j] << " * ";
        // each new max is printed
        std::cout << nStr[i + nbAdjacent - 1] << " = " << prod << std::endl;
    }
    prod = 1;
}
```

and it prints this:

```
7 * 3 * 1 * 6 * 7 * 1 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 3 * 1 * 3 * 3 = 5000940
4 * 9 * 1 * 9 * 2 * 2 * 5 * 1 * 1 * 9 * 6 * 7 * 4 = 9797760
9 * 2 * 2 * 5 * 1 * 1 * 9 * 6 * 7 * 4 * 4 * 2 * 6 = 13063680
2 * 5 * 1 * 1 * 9 * 6 * 7 * 4 * 4 * 2 * 6 * 5 * 7 = 25401600
5 * 1 * 1 * 9 * 6 * 7 * 4 * 4 * 2 * 6 * 5 * 7 * 4 = 50803200
1 * 1 * 9 * 6 * 7 * 4 * 4 * 2 * 6 * 5 * 7 * 4 * 7 = 71124480
1 * 9 * 6 * 7 * 4 * 4 * 2 * 6 * 5 * 7 * 4 * 7 * 4 = 284497920
9 * 6 * 7 * 4 * 4 * 2 * 6 * 5 * 7 * 4 * 7 * 4 * 2 = 568995840
5 * 3 * 4 * 9 * 1 * 9 * 4 * 9 * 3 * 4 * 9 * 6 * 9 = 1020366720
3 * 4 * 9 * 1 * 9 * 4 * 9 * 3 * 4 * 9 * 6 * 9 * 8 = 1632586752
9 * 1 * 9 * 4 * 9 * 3 * 4 * 9 * 6 * 9 * 8 * 3 * 5 = 2040733440
8 * 6 * 9 * 4 * 7 * 8 * 8 * 5 * 1 * 8 * 4 * 3 * 8 = 2972712960
```

I checked for index error in the for loops but found nothing wrong...

Comment: What are the correct results supposed to be? And what result do you get?

Comment: `main` is missing, for one thing.[`mre] highly recommended. As requested above include expected output, but also include inputs.

Comment: Correct result  is 23514624000, I get 2972712960 ( last line) the goal is to calculate the largest product of 13 consecutive numbers in nStr ( that i have shortened here )
also, I didn't include main or anything outside because my program groups all of the problems and is huge

Comment: `max` is probably a 32-bit integer - `INT_MAX` is a bit over 2-billion, and you've gone past that, so while `prod` is correct `max` won't be, and your `prod > max` test will stop working properly.  Make them both `uint64_t`.

Comment: Please note that `max` and `prod` have different types.

Comment: Where is the magic number 988 coming from? Should that really be `nStr.size() - nbAdjacent - 1` or something?

Comment: Indeed I thought `prod` was exeeding the limit but `max` has the same problem... setting it uint64_t solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

One problem in your solution is that you iterate up including `988`, which is incorrect because you will access `nStr[i + j] = nStr[988+12]=nStr[1000]` which is out of bounds and contains garbage.
As others pointed out, the max solution you could get is `9^13` which requires at least 42 bits (`log2(9^13)=41.2`), therefore use something like `long long int` that is guaranteed to have 64 bits on all architectures.
As a tip, try to avoid hard-coding values such as `988` in your program but to compute them.

For the code, a possible improvement is to use a sliding window rather than computing the product each time, and to keep track of the current 13 digits multiplied. You then divide by the last digit and multiplying by the new one each loop iteration. This provides a speedup on the solution, that will be `O(n)` rather than `O(s*n)`. Since some digits might be zero, we can keep a counter of how many digits are 0 in our window and if this counter is >0 we will know that the product is 0.

Here a sample solution in c++ that outputs the right result.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const string digits = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
const int nAdj = 13;

int main()
{
    int n = digits.size();
    long long int prod = 1;
    long long int max = 0;
    int zeros = 0;

    // precompute sliding window
    for (int i = 0; i < nAdj-1; ++i)
    {
        int d = digits[i]-'0';
        if(d==0) ++zeros;
        else prod *= d;
    }

    for (int i = nAdj-1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        // add new digit
        int d = digits[i]-'0';
        if(d==0) ++zeros;
        else prod *= d;

        //check best
        if(zeros == 0)
        {
            if(prod > max) max = prod;
        }

        //remove last digit
        d = digits[i-nAdj+1]-'0';
        if(d==0) --zeros;
        else prod /= d;
    }

    cout << "The max is: " << max << endl; // 23514624000
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
std::string returnStr(std::string text, int index){
    std::string result = "";

    for (int i = index; i < text.size() && result.size() != 13; i++)
        result += text[i];
    if (result.size() == 13)
        return result;
    else
        return "";
}
long long int returnProduct(std::string str){
    int b = 0;
    long long int p = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++){
        b = str[i];
        b -= 48;
        p *= b;
    }
    return p;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::string text = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    long long int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++)
    {
        std::string s = returnStr(text, i);
        if (s != ""){
            long long int p = returnProduct(s);
            
            
            if (p>max)
                max = p;
        }

    }
    std::cout << max << std::endl;
    std::system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)